# Excel VBA: Summing rows and columns

Tags: vba, excel

Very new to VBA and working on a project. I have a file that contains sales data for 1000 products (rows) across 50 days (columns).

In the last column, I want to display the total sums for each product across each day. What is the best way to accomplish this? Should I do a for-next loop?

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub testsum()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BJ1") = "Sum"

Range("BJ2:BJ1001").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B2:BI1001"))

End Sub
```

I know this isn't right because I am getting the sum of sales for all 1000 products for 50 days vs. only getting the sum of each product (Row) for all days.

Hope I wasn't confusing in explaining. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using Pivot Tables? Or even normal tables, just put the formula to sum each row product in the last column, and every time you insert a new day, the formula will update

Answer (score 2):

You can either loop through all 1000 rows, or you can use an Excel formula to do the calculation and then set the value to what was calculated.

Method using a formula:

```
Sub testsum()    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BJ1") = "Sum"

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BJ2:BJ1001")
        .Formula = "=SUM(B2:BI2)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```